# Disqus problems in IE? Conflicts with ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, disqus

Anyone having problems with discus in IE? Works fine in FF but reports problem with thread.js in IE. (runtime error)

Disqus works fine on other sites in IE, but non on mine. Maybe ASP.NET conflict.

I have jQuery and addthis on the page but if I comment these the problem remains.

Comment: The problem seems to have been fixed by Disqus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid I don't see errors when I visit the link above.

You should probably give details for the error and also let us know which version of IE you're using and on what OS.

Perhaps with some more I (or someone else on SO) can help you. However, you might want to check out some other Disqus resources such as:

http://groups.google.com/group/disqus-dev

Comment: More of a comment than an answer?